# How to update, not reload, UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

My question may be looks simple, but it doesn't work. I searched a lot and try a lot of methods, but it doesn't want work!

So, I have an UITableView. In the background one of my functions work and detect, if a new message has been received, it writes this value into Core Data and I want to add badges on my cells when I receive a new message.

But when I try this:

```
func reloadTableView() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

it doesn't update my tableView and doesn't show new badges. For this, I need:

1. Change my controller and return to it
2. Or I need drag my tableView to top and leave it

in these cases it will show my badges.

So, how can I **update** my tableView to show new added badges without described above 2 methods?

**UPDATE**

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I have 2 files: ContactsTableViewController and Messages.swift.

In my Messages.swift I handle new messages and when I receive a new message I get in logs:

```
print("New message for \(user.jidStr)")
ContactsTableViewController().reloadTableView()
```

In my ContactsTableViewController:

```
func reloadTableView() {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    print("updated")
}
```

It reloads my tableView, as I get `updated` message in logs, but it doesn't updated it and my badges

Comment: How did you create your table view?  Where have you implemented its datasource and delegate?

Comment: @Simon `class ContactsTableViewController: UITableViewController {` and I've added an screenshot. Please, look at it in my question

Comment: Try to check that reloadTableView() is called from the main thread.

Comment: @SuttikeatWitchayakul without dispatch_async? I tried it too. Nothing

Comment: where do you call the function from?

Comment: Not in the reloadTableView() function, but where the reloadTableView() is called.

Comment: @Lukas inside of my viewController class

Comment: can you post how you call it, it may be that it never gets to that line

Comment: @Lukas it works JUST when I use this `override func viewDidLoad() {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "reloadTableView", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }` . Is it bad to use such mechanism?

Comment: Its better to reload the table only when the model change, make sure you set tableView.datasource = self and delegate = self in view didLoad

Comment: @Lukas yes, I think so. I set it, as you said, but when I call my function with: `ContactsTableViewController().reloadTableView()` it doesn't call my function from ContactsTableViewController

Comment: @Lukas it's because of `delegate and dataSource = self`. When I remove them - it works, but doesn't update my tableView

Comment: First of, call it just as: reloadTableView() not on the vc().reload... and give us the code where you call this function. or just post the entire class. It'll make it easier to understand what you're trying to do and where you're failing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94173/discussion-between-orkhan-alizade-and-lukas).

Comment: @Lukas please, join the chat

Answer (score 2):

Try to update only cells that receive new message with:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

where `row` - the row of your cell in it section that receive the message

Answer (score 1):

Example in Objective-C:

```
[_tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Example in Swift 2.0:

```
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexSet, indexSetWithIndex:0], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the NSOperationQeue?

```
func reloadTableView() {
  NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Edit (because I can't comment)

```
override func viewDidLoad() { NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "reloadTableView", userInfo: nil, repeats: true) }
```

If you are using something like this you call the update function every second and this doesn't make sense. You should call it after getting your data

Answer (score 0):

The reloadData should work... ( I think it is better to call it on the main thread. )

Have you checked that your objects array is correct ? If it comes from a CoreData request, it may use the cache. Be sure that you have synchronized the CoreDataContext ( by calling the save method on the context after your insertion ) and that your fetch returns the last created objects.

Just a guess…